# How to get mongodb version from mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Simple, with the mongo cli:

```
db.version ()
```

How can I do the same with mongoose? How can I send a custom command?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the native mongo driver's [`Admin#buildInfo`](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/admin.html#buildinfo) method for that via your Mongoose connection:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', function(err){
  var admin = new mongoose.mongo.Admin(mongoose.connection.db);
  admin.buildInfo(function (err, info) {
     console.log(info.version);
  });
});
```

Comment: Just a comment, if you're not using the mongodb module you'll need to point to `require("mongoose/node_modules/mongodb")`

Comment: The mongodb module used by mongoose is exposed as require('mongoose').mongo. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-mongo

Comment: this seems no more working with mongoose 7

Answer (score 5):

You can query the `buildInfo` directly from your Mongoose connection.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', function(err) {
    mongoose.db.command({ buildInfo: 1 }, function (err, info) {
        console.log(info.version);
    });
});
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/buildInfo/#dbcmd.buildInfo

Answer (score 2):

Try this one, it will give you the verion of both MongoDB and Mongoose

```
async function run() {
    var admin = new mongoose.mongo.Admin(mongoose.connection.db);
    admin.buildInfo(function (err, info) {
       console.log(`mongodb: ${info.version}`);
       console.log(`mongoose: ${mongoose.version}`);
    });
}

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('MongoDB connected');
        run();
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```