# MongoError: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$addFields'

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

MongoError: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$addFields'.
"mongoose": "^4.5.8"
My sourcecode:

```
                Post.aggregate(
                    [{
                        $addFields: {
                            userName: { $concat: [ "$author.firstName", " ", "$author.lastName" ] }
                        }
                        //$project: { userName: { $concat: [ "$author.firstName", " ", "$author.lastName" ] } } //this is ok!
                    }],
                    function (err, result) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                            return;
                        }
                        console.log(result);
                    }
                )
```

Post model:

```
let schema = {
id: "post",
properties: {
    content: {type: "string"},
    author: {
        type: "object",
        id: {type: "string"},
        avatar: {type: "string"},
        firstName: {type: "string"},
        lastName: {type: "string"},
        status: {type: "string"}
    },
    category: {
        type: "object",
        id: {type: "string"},
        name: {type: "string"}
    },
    images: {
        type: "array",
        items: {
            type: "object",
            properties: {
                filePath: {type: "string"},
            }
        }
    },
    video: {
        type: "object",
        thumbnail: {type: "string"},
        filePath: {type: "string"}
    },
    likes: {
        type: "array",
        items: {
            type: "object",
            properties: {
                userId: {type: "string"},
                status: {type: "string"},
                _id   : {type: "string", default: null}
            }
        }
    },
    shares: {
        type: "array",
        items: {
            type: "object",
            properties: {
                userId: {type: "string"},
                status: {type: "string"},
                destination: {type: "string"}, //FACEBOOK|TWISTER|GOOGLE
                _id        : {type: "string", default: null}
            }
        }
    },
    favorites: {
        type: "array",
        items: {
            type: "object",
            properties: {
                userId: {type: "string"},
                status: {type: "string"},
                _id   : {type: "string", default: null}
            }
        }
    },
    comments: {
        type: "array",
        items: {
            type: "object",
            properties: {
                commentId: {type: "string"},
                _deleted: {type: "Date", default: ''},
                _id     : {type: "string", default: null}
            }
        }
    },
    _created: {type: "Date", default: Date.now},
    _deleted: {type: "Date", default: ''},
    _updated: {type: "Date", default: ''}
}
```

Comment: what is version on mongodb? `$addFields` is introduced in 3.4

Comment: mongodb's version is ^4.5.8

Comment: in packge.json:
"mongoose": "^4.5.8",
"mongoose-json-select": "^0.2.1",
"mongoose-unique-validator": "^1.0.2",

Comment: Check the version using the answer in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311305/how-to-get-mongodb-version-from-mongoose

Comment: I checked and mongodb's version is 3.2.9. thank you!

Comment: @sidgate You should post that as the answer.

Answer (score 9):

[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) is introduced in Mongo 3.4 version. As you have commented that you are using mongo 3.2.9, the mentioned query won't work.

If you cannot update the mongo version for some reason, then you have to use following approach where you need to iterate over each document and set the new field

```
Post.find({}).forEach(function(post){
  post.findOneAndUpdate({_id: post._id}, 
      {$set: {userName: post.author.firstName + " " + post.author.lastName }})
});
```

Comment: Modifying the original documents is a poor workaround. The commented out `$project` in the OP's question is the right workaround.

Comment: Thank you very much! I updated the mongo version and solved my problem

Comment: @JohnnyHK can you explain why the $project solution is correct? I am looking for answers to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49989101/mongoerror-unrecognized-pipeline-stage-name-changestream