# How to watch for an updated boolean value in a pymongo document?

Tags: python-3.x, pymongo-3.x

I am trying to listen for an update to a collection using `pymongo 3.6.1`.

The collection gets updated with a document that looks something like this:

```
{"End_Word":"bit","Success":true,"Score":1,"Term_Index":5}
```

Where if the key `Success` gets updated to `true` *in any of the documents* a `def dosomething()` gets called.

The [mongodb api](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.watch) documentation shows this example, as a first step:

```
with db.collection.watch() as stream:
    for change in stream:
        print(change)
```

In attempting to replicate this I am getting a `OperationFailure: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$changeStream'` error. When researching other's with similar [issues on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43630875/mongoerror-unrecognized-pipeline-stage-name-addfields) The answer was `connection driver` versions.  I don't think this is the case here:

[image]

Code:

```
db_name = 'mapstore'
coll_name = 'oxygen'

MONGO_DB_DRIVER = pymongo atlas M2 instance driver
conn = pymongo.MongoClient(MONGO_DB_DRIVER)
db = conn[db_name]
print(db.collection_names())
```

[image]

#### Update:

I also looked in these places

[How to listen for changes to a MongoDB collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691316/how-to-listen-for-changes-to-a-mongodb-collection)
https://docs.mongodb.com/master/changeStreams/

What is the right approach?

Comment: The issue may be with the server version here and not pymongo driver version. Can you please check the server version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below error

```
OperationFailure: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$changeStream'
```

Indicates that your Mongodb server is below `3.6.0` and that is why it doesn't recognize this command. Even though you have latest client, doesn't change how the server behaves

Comment: So there is no way to use this operation with MongoDB Atlas? The server version on Mongo's cloud service is defaulting to is 3.4.14.  :(

Comment: `Atlas supports creating M10+ paid tier clusters with the following MongoDB versions:

MongoDB 3.2
MongoDB 3.4
MongoDB 3.6
M0 Free Tier and M2/M5 shared tier clusters only support MongoDB 3.4.`