# MongoError: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$changeStream'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

We are getting this error:

```
   MongoError: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$changeStream'
        at queryCallback (/Users/alexamil/WebstormProjects/nabisco/cdt-now/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:244:25)
        at /Users/alexamil/WebstormProjects/nabisco/cdt-now/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:544:18
        at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
        at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
```

We have this file, which will update some caches on our server:

```
'use strict';

import caches = require('../../models/caches');

import {Phase, Acquisition, Category, FunctionalGroup, Role, User, Workstream} from "../../models";

Acquisition.watch().on('change', function (c) {
  console.log('acq change:', c);
});

Category.watch().on('change', function (c) {
  console.log('category change:', c);
});

FunctionalGroup.watch().on('change', function (c) {
  console.log('functional team change:', c);
});

Role.watch().on('change', function (c) {
  console.log('role change:', c);
});

User.watch().on('change', function (c) {
  console.log('user change:', c);
});

Workstream.watch().on('change', function (c) {
  console.log('workstream change:', c);
});
```

we are migrating from Mongo 2.6 to Mongo 3.4, so some of our data might be missing fields.

Does anyone know how to mitigate this error?

We are now using mongoose version `5.0.16`.

Comment: Based on the [official doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/): **You can only open a change stream against replica sets or sharded clusters** Did you met the requirement?

Comment: yeah I am connected to a replica set

Comment: [Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) say change streams are `New in version 3.6.`

Comment: And I'm not sure if mongoose already fully deploy that functionality.  Based on the doc, it should be used as a generator.  But, I'm really interested in such use case with event listener since it is pretty new.

Comment: Ohhh so I need to be on Mongo 3.6, not Mongo 3.4

Comment: Well... basically it was added since Mongo 3.6...  Does it work now?

Comment: We can't upgrade to 3.4 because we are stuck on 3.4 in production. But I have a lib that reads from the oplog (it uses change streams TMK but seems to work)...https://github.com/ORESoftware/oplog.rx.... we will have to use Model.watch() later in the future.

Answer (score 2):

[Change streams are new in MongoDB 3.6.](http://thecodebarbarian.com/a-nodejs-perspective-on-mongodb-36-change-streams.html#change-streams-in-mongoose) If you use `MyModel.watch()` in mongoose when connected to an older version of the MongoDB server, you'll get this error.