# Node JS with MongoDB Aggrigate with $unwind not working $addFields, $sort, $match in aggregation pipeline

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, aggregate, pipeline

I am new to Node Js. I'm trying to solve an aggregate with unwind keyword. But when I try to add a new field or sort or match it returns an error like this

```
error": {
        "ok": 0,
        "errmsg": "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$addFields'",
        "code": 16436,
        "name": "MongoError",
        "statusCode": 500,
        "status": "error"
```

I write code like the following (only the part)

````
      $addFields: {
        month: '$_id'
      }
    },
    {
      $sort: {
        month: 1
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0
      }
    }```
````

Comment: which version of Mongo you're using?

Comment: I am using Node version v3.2.16-rc0. Because my system is win 10 32 bit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoError: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$addFields'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43630875/mongoerror-unrecognized-pipeline-stage-name-addfields)